# Запись объектов класса в файл json

Tags: php, json

Есть некоторый массив, содержащий объекты определенного класса `$array`. Вопрос, как закодировать этот массив в json формат, если `json_encode($array)` не работает (получается `{[]}` в результате)?

Comment: Можно экземпляры класса приводить к типу `array` через `(array) $a`, но боюсь вам такой результат не подойдёт. Вам нужно будет написать функционал, который будет знать как каждый класс преобразовать в массив или json.

Comment: @ArchDemon, т.е. функции, которая делала бы это за меня не существует?

Comment: Я вам её написал. Попробуйте, если вас это устроит, то пользуйтесь наздоровье

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы класс сериализировался в Json он должен реализовывать интерфейс [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.jsonserializable.php).

Если в Вашем массиве хранятся объекты **определенного** класса, думаю не составит труда реализовать этот интерфейс.

```
class Arr implements JsonSerializable {
public function jsonSerialize(){
        return [
            'a' => 'b'
        ];
    }
}

$arr = [];
$arr[] = new Arr();
$arr[] = new Arr();
$arr[] = new Arr();
$arr[] = new Arr();

print_r(json_encode($arr));
```

На выходе мы получим:

`[{"a":"b"},{"a":"b"},{"a":"b"},{"a":"b"}]`